# Nested generic types in static method

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I was trying to develop a generic method that could convert a JSON to a generic object that would have another instantiable generic object inside so I could use it as a parser in several places in my application.

I had thought of the following solution, but it doesn't work:

```
public static <T, K> T<K> jsonToObjectType(String json, TypeReference<T<K>> type) {
    // More code
}
```

Is there any way to be able to perform such a method?

Comment: Without any indication of what type `T` is, what use is knowing that it has generic type parameter `K`?

Comment: @khelwood that's a good question (^o^)

Comment: Just get rid of `K`: `public static <T> T jsonToObjectType(String json, TypeReference<T> type)`. So what if it allows `T` to be non-generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `public static <T, K> T<K>`

Your `T` has no bounds, meaning, T can be anything. It could be `String`.

String has no generics, so how can `T<K>` make sense? It doesn't, hence, java doesn't let you compile this.

I guess you could conceive of the notion of: "T is some specific type, could be anything, as long as it has exactly 1 generics param", but java doesn't have this, and never will, because that is structural type and java doesn't do that.

However, note that a generics param can be **any type**, notably include types that are themselves parameterized. Here is a trival example:

```
public static <T> T coalesce(T a, T b) {
    return a == null ? b : a;
}
```

This method can be used like so:

```
String a = null;
String b = "Hello";

coalesce(a, b).toLowerCase();
```

There is absolutely no problem feeding it 2 `List<String>`, at which point the expression `coalesce(listA, listB)` would be of type `List<String>`. And that's just with `<T>`, not with this `<T, K>` stuff.

I don't quite know what `jsonToObjectType` is supposed to do, but assuming that it is supposed to take a string that contains JSON + some super-type-token (you can search the web for that term), which I'm 99.9% certain you have, then just remove K from it all, and you get precisely what you wanted:

```
public static <T> T jsonToObjectType(String json, TypeReference<T> type) {
   // code here 
}
```

and you can call it like so:

```
String json = "[\"Hello\", \"World!\"]";
List<String> list = jsonToObjectType(json, new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});
```

and it'll compile without warnings or errors and works.